# Different Expanded/Selected state in multiple TreeViews with same ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

TLDR:
How to manage a different IsExpanded/IsSelected state of the same ViewModel in multiple views?

Long Version:
I have a good working App with a huge TreeView. The app has a lot few functions that select, expand and collapse the TreeView items. So the ViewModel contains a IsExpanded/IsSelected property for each TreeNode (bound to the TreeViewItem by a Style).
Now I have the requirement to avoid to much scrolling in this Tree. So the idea is to provide a second TreeView (maybe more..) with a root element selected from the first Tree).
The problem is that both TreeView's depend on the same IsExpanded/IsSelected properties, but I want to control these states for each Tree differently) and I have no good idea how update the IsExpanded/IsSelected logic to make it work with multiple TreeViews.

All functions that manipulate these states know the in which Tree they are used, because they depend on a parent TreeVM ViewModel.
I thought to have a IsExpanded/IsSelected ObservableCollection but can't find a good way to bind the TreeViewItem-properties to the collection (two-way).

App.xaml:

```
<Application
    x:Class="MultiTree.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiTree"
>
    <Application.Resources />
    <Application.MainWindow>
        <local:MainWindow />
    </Application.MainWindow>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MultiTree
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            MainWindow.Loaded += (ws, we) => {
                MainWindow.DataContext = new AppVM();
            };
            MainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Window
    x:Class="MultiTree.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiTree"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450">
    <Window.Resources />
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Views}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TreeView
                    Margin="5"
                    Background="Gainsboro"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Root.Nodes}">
                    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

AppVM.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MultiTree
{

    public class Bindable : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class TreeNode : Bindable
    {
        public TreeNode(string name, IEnumerable<TreeNode> nodes = null)
        {
            Name = name;
            if (nodes == null)
                _nodes = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>();
            else
                _nodes = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>(nodes);
        }

        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool _isSelected;

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get => _isSelected;
            set {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool _isExpanded;

        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get => _isExpanded;
            set {
                _isExpanded = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<TreeNode> _nodes;

        public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Nodes => _nodes;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// "Root" for each TreeView, known by all functions that expand/collapse&select
    /// </summary>
    public class TreeVM : Bindable
    {
        private TreeNode _root;

        public TreeNode Root
        {
            get => _root;
            set {
                _root = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public class AppVM : Bindable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Contains all TreeNodes
        /// </summary>
        private readonly TreeNode RootNode;

        public AppVM()
        {
            RootNode = new TreeNode("ROOT", new[] {
                new TreeNode("A", new [] {
                    new TreeNode("B", new [] {
                        new TreeNode("C", new [] {
                            new TreeNode("D")
                        })
                    }),
                    new TreeNode("E", new [] {
                        new TreeNode("F", new [] {
                            new TreeNode("G", new [] {
                                new TreeNode("H"),
                                new TreeNode("I")
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            });

            Views.Add(new TreeVM() { Root = RootNode });
            Views.Add(new TreeVM() { Root = RootNode.Nodes.First() });
        }

        private ObservableCollection<TreeVM> _views = new ObservableCollection<TreeVM>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Each Tree can contain all or a subset of TreeNodes
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<TreeVM> Views
        {
            get => _views;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is very welcome :-)

Comment: Why can't you create a separate view model instance per view?

Comment: I wanted to avoid this, because the VM‘s have a few „runtime“ properties not stored in the model.

Comment: It makes no sense to bind several controls to a single property if don't want the controls to be synchronized.

Comment: Right, this is the reason why I want to use the same ViewModels. The only difference is which Item is selected as root.

Comment: Then you would need a collection of objects with a `bool` property in the view model and bind to these properties from the views.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds promising. Could you please describe this approach more detailed?  I already wanted to go in this direction, but I was thinking of a MultiValueConverter for IsSelected - in my opinion the ConvertBack method is not sufficient to set the value by XAML.

Comment: No, it's not. That's why you need to bind to the `bool` property of the composite object directly, i.e. you create a type `X´ with several bool properties and then you bind to them using a path like for example `X.First`.